# return model instance without tuple when case statement is used in SQLAlchemy + FastAPI

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Let's say I have an API, by calling it we get a list of posts, for each post I want to send a value whether that post is editable or not by the logged-in user in the response. so for that I'm using Case statement from SQLAlchemy and based on the logged-in user ID I'm returning true or false

The code looks like below

```
is_editable_expr = case(
    [
        (Post.user_id == current_user.id, True),
    ],
    else_=False,
).label("is_editable")
data = db_session.query(Post, is_editable_expr).order_by(Post.created_at.desc()).join(User).all()
```

I'm using FastAPI and when it tries to serialize the data it fails because the value returned by this is ORM looks like

```
[(<Post title=Todo title description=A short description about your todo>, False), ...]
```

here the post model instance is inside the tuple and `is_editable` is directly accessible. the Post pydantic model looks like this

```
class Post(BaseModel):

    id: int
    title: str,
    description: str,
    user: User
    is_active: bool
    is_editable: bool

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

since the orm instance itself is inside tuple while serializing it's failing and cannot access title/descriptions etc. I want my response to be a list of Post and it should look like this

```
[
    {
       "title":"title name",
       "description":"some long description",
       "is_editable":true
    },
  ...
]
```

Can anyone please advice or suggest how can I make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because of your query definition: `db_session.query(Post, is_editable_expr)`

So basically the second item in the tuple is your `is_editable` expression

I would rather avoid doing it in the database and would do a simple loop to do it on the server:

```py
data = (db_session.query(Post)
                  .order_by(Post.created_at.desc())
                  .join(User)
                  .all())
for post in data:
    post.is_editable = post.user_id == current_user.id
```

Comment: isn't it possible to do this directly via the SQLAlchemy query itself? because doing this through a normal loop I think is inefficient.

Comment: @AashayAmballi there is no other way as I'm aware. there are computed columns, but they only work when they depend on other columns in the table. a for loop is not inefficient btw, it's O(n) which is basically the same as it takes to run in the database anyways (the database might run it in parallel on multiple threads to improve performance by a constant factor, but it's still O(n), so basically no performance hit)

Comment: okay, I'm new to SQLAlchemy. In Django, if we use annotate method, the custom fields generally get mapped to the model instance. so there is no way we can do this in SQLAlchemy without any post-processing?

Comment: @AashayAmballi I don't think there are. At least I'm not aware of them